# hibernate property string length question

Tags: hibernate

I have an object mapped in hibernate like so:

```
<property name="firstname" type="string">
  <column name="FIRSTNAME" not-null="true" />
</property>

<property name=description" type="string">
  <column name="DESCRIPTION" />
</property>
```

I'm using an ANT script to generate the database schema from the mapping file and the db fields get created with type VARCHAR size 255.

My question is, how do I specify that the max length of the FIRSTNAME field is 25, and the max length of the DESCRIPTION field is 1000?  I tried adding a length attribute to the property tag (as follows) but it didn't work:

```
<property name=description" type="string" length="1000">
  <column name="DESCRIPTION" />
</property>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="description" length="100" />
        </property>
```

you need to place it to the column.

Comment: awesome .. you saved me from buying Asprin