# Hibernate, MySQL - Data truncation: Data too long for column exception message

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, truncation

I understand what this message means, but I do not understand why it is giving this message. I say this because I'm not trying to update this field.

**Column definition:**

```
@Column(name="company_name")
private String companyName;
```

Then I create a Query using EntityManager.

**Query**

```
query = em.createQuery("update Client set companyName = :companyName" +
                " where id = :id");

query.setParameter("companyName", client.getCompanyName());
query.setParameter("id", client.getId());

query.executeUpdate();
```

And the exception reads: `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'company_cnpj' at row 1`

But I'm not changing the 'company_cnpj' row. Why is it giving me this error?

Answer (score 2):

Strings in the database always have a length; since you didn't specify one, it defaults to 255.  This post tells you how to change it:

[hibernate property string length question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809787/hibernate-property-string-length-question)